# Как правильно написать регулярное выражение в pattern, чтоб input принимал или пустую строчку "" или только буквы

Tags: javascript, html, input

если regex= `^[А-ЯА-яA-Za-z0-9]{1,15}$|^$`  ругается на пустую строчку

```
<form>
  <input name="color" required pattern="^[А-ЯА-яA-Za-z0-9]{1,15}$|^$">
  <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто надо убрать `required`, который как раз таки не пропускал пустую строку. `pattern` и так не пропустит, если будет что-то другое, кроме цифр и букв.

```html
<form>
  <input name="color" pattern="^[А-ЯА-яA-Za-z0-9]{1,15}$">
  <button type="submit">Кнопка</button>
</form>
```